# Windows server 2008 R2 High Memory Utilization

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, memory-usage, memory-leak, crystalreports

We are running a VM with Windows server 2008 R2, we see the physical memory utilization to be close to 100% always. Machine is running crystal reports server.

Task manager counts to 99% memory Utilization, where a sum memory used by all the processes from tasklist accounts for only 1/4 of the total available memory. Not sure if their is a memory leak, if so how to find and patch it ?

I agree going by summing up the tasklist values is not the correct approach as it may not account for cached and so on, but I am guessing it can be the first place to start with.

### Physical Memory (MB)

Total 32767
Cached 120
Available 117
Free 0

### Kernel memory (MB)

Paged 381
Nonpaged 200

### System

### ----

Commit (GB) 19/63

Comment: Do you have Microsoft SQL Server installed on the machine?

Comment: What's the VM platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a symptom of [agressive File System Caching](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976618).

Download [RAMMap from Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) to find out what is taking up all this memory

As described in the kb article, you need to look for large Available or Standby Memory claims in the "Metafile" usage category:

[image: Credit: Microsof (KB976618)]